# Dynamically change the color or text based on value with Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hey guys looking for some assistance with changing the color of text based on value. If the value is zero or negative I want it to be red, and if the value is + I want it to be green. Below is just a little bit of code from the full html but I think these are the key parts. [Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/258cekzy/3/) As you can see the table is dynamic. As you input data into the starting amount it will automatically calculate it for the ending  amount. The starting amount adds to the bill amount which produces the total amount number. I am also not sure if the event "onchange" is correct. Thank you for your input and advise in advanced.

```
<p><b>Starting Amount: &#36; <input id="money" type="number"   onkeyup="calc()"></b></p>

<table>
<tr>
<th>Bill Ammount</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="number"  class="billAmt" id="billAmt" onkeyup="calc()">      </td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="hidden" id="total" name="total" value="0">
<p><b>Ending Amount: &#36; <span id="totalAmt"         onchange="colorChange(this)">0</span></b></p>

<script type="text/Javascript">
var myElement = document.getElementById('totalAmt');
function colorChange() {
    if('myElement' > 0) {
        totalAmt.style.color = 'green'; 
        } else {
                totalAmt.style.color = 'red';
    }
}


function calc() {
var money = parseInt(document.querySelector('#money').value) || 0;
var bills = document.querySelectorAll('table tr input.billAmt') ;
var billTotal = 0;

for (i = 0; i < bills.length; i++) {
  billTotal += parseInt(bills[i].value) || 0;
}

totalAmt.innerHTML = money + billTotal;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your variable is named `myElement` but you're using `totalAmt` everywhere else in your javascript. Turn `var myElement = ...` into `var totalAmt = ...` and some more of your code will start working.

Comment: onChange won't work on a span element, just move your colour change code to the end of your calc and set totalAmt.style.color to whatever colour you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `myElement.innerHTML` instead of `myElement` in the if condition and invoke the changeColor function at last of calc

```js
var myElement = document.getElementById('totalAmt');

function colorChange() {
  if (myElement.innerHTML <= 0) {

    totalAmt.style.color = 'red';
  } else {
    totalAmt.style.color = 'green';
  }
}


function calc() {

  var money = parseInt(document.querySelector('#money').value) || 0;
  var bills = document.querySelectorAll('table tr input.billAmt');
  var billTotal = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < bills.length; i++) {
    billTotal += parseInt(bills[i].value) || 0;
  }

  totalAmt.innerHTML = money + billTotal;
  colorChange();
}
```

```html
<p><b>Starting Amount: &#36; <input id="money" type="number" onkeyup="calc()"></b></p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Bill Ammount</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" class="billAmt" id="billAmt" onkeyup="calc()"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="hidden" id="total" name="total" value="0">
<p><b>Ending Amount: &#36; <span id="totalAmt">0</span></b></p>
```

Comment: With all respect, this code is low quality. Why to use two functions if you can handle it easily just in one? You are passing `this` arg inside `colorChange` function. Why? You are not even referencing to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can reach the desired result using just one function. Instead of checking the DOM element's `innerHTML` or `textContext` to get the amount, just refer to the variables holding it.

```js
var myElement = document.getElementById('totalAmt');

function calc() {
  var money = parseInt(document.querySelector('#money').value) || 0;
  var bills = document.querySelectorAll('table tr input.billAmt');
  var billTotal = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < bills.length; i++) {
    billTotal += parseInt(bills[i].value) || 0;
  }
  totalAmt.innerHTML = money + billTotal;
  myElement.style.color = money + billTotal <= 0 ? 'red' : 'green';
  
}
```

```html
<p><b>Starting Amount: &#36; <input id="money" type="number" onkeyup="calc()"></b></p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Bill Ammount</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" class="billAmt" id="billAmt" onkeyup="calc()"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="hidden" id="total" name="total" value="0">
<p><b>Ending Amount: &#36; <span id="totalAmt">0</span></b></p>
```

Comment: appreciating the code. But in my point of view, using two function / one function is upto the OP. what if the OP want to invoke the function from anywhere else. We can't predict how OP think. Your code is good if the function called only once. but the main advantage of using functions is reuse

Comment: @SagarV Agreed but just please do not duplicate the same errors which the OP made. Delete that `this` keyword from the function at least (:

Comment: Thanks and sorry it was a mistake happened when combining the Fiddle code(html) and the code I edited(js)

Comment: I tried upvoting for this alternate code. But limit reached.

Comment: @SagarV Limit reached? :O

Comment: @SagarV I didn't even know that there's a limit for upvotes! ;o

Comment: FYI , per day you can cast only 40 votes ( up & down)

Answer (score 1):

A couple issues with your original code:

1 - you were checking if the string `myElement` was greater than zero, instead of the innerHTML of the element you selected.

2 - using `innerHTML()` to change the contents of an element doesn't fire an onchange event.  In my code, I call your `colorChange` function at the end of the calc function, so if you decide to add another field to it (tax or something), it will be called after the total is calculated.

```js
function colorChange() {
  var myElement = document.getElementById('totalAmt');

  if (myElement.innerHTML > 0) {
    totalAmt.style.color = 'green';
  } else {
    totalAmt.style.color = 'red';
  }
}


function calc() {
  var money = parseInt(document.querySelector('#money').value) || 0;
  var bills = document.querySelectorAll('table tr input.billAmt');
  var billTotal = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < bills.length; i++) {
    billTotal += parseInt(bills[i].value) || 0;
  }

  totalAmt.innerHTML = money + billTotal;
  colorChange()
}
```

```html
<p><b>Starting Amount: &#36; <input id="money" type="number"   onkeyup="calc()"></b></p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Bill Ammount</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" class="billAmt" id="billAmt" onkeyup="calc()"> </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="hidden" id="total" name="total" value="0">
<p><b>Ending Amount: &#36; <span id="totalAmt">0</span></b></p>
```